Oracle APEX Dynamic Action call to package throwing error "ORA-06550: line 11, column 19: PLS-00302: component 'GET_EMP_INFO' must be declared"
I have a page item with dynamic action (on change).  This works (other processes fire).  I've added an action to call a procedure in a package to get employee info.  When I try to validate, that call in APEX is throwing the error "ORA-06550: line 11, column 19: PLS-00302: component 'GET_EMP_INFO' must be declared".
I can execute the procedure in the package directly (in Toad) and I get the expected output.  So I don't think the procedure is the issue.
Here's the APEX dynamic action call (Execute Server-side code > PL/SQL).  Can you tell what's causing the error?
DECLARE
    l_job_code varchar(200);
    l_job_title varchar(200);
    l_position_number varchar(200);
    l_position_suffix varchar(200);
    l_org_number varchar(200);
    l_org_name varchar(200);

BEGIN
    --call procedure in package and directly assign output to page items (and some vars)
    hri.pkg_apex_eab.get_emp_info (
        in_ee                               => :P2_EE,
        out_emp_employee_number             => :P2_EE_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
        out_emp_full_name                   => :P2_EE_FULL_NAME,
        out_emp_email_address               => :P2_EE_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        out_emp_user_name                   => :P2_EE_USER_NAME,
        out_emp_job_classification_code     => l_job_code,
        out_emp_job_classification_title    => l_job_title,
        out_emp_position_number             => l_position_number,
        out_emp_position_suffix             => l_position_suffix,
        out_emp_working_title               => l_position_suffix,
        out_emp_org_number                  => l_org_number,
        out_emp_org_name                    => l_org_name,
        out_supv_employee_number            => :P2_EE_SUPV_EID,
        out_supv_full_name                  => :P2_EE_SUPV_FULLNAME,
        out_supv_user_name                  => :P2_EE_SUPV_USERNAME,
        out_supv_email_address              => :P2_EE_SUPV_EMAIL);

        --combine some return vars and assign to page items
        :P2_EE_JOB := l_job_code || '.' || l_job_title;
        :P2_EE_POSITION := l_position_number || '.' || l_position_suffix || '.' || l_working_title;
        :P2_EE_ORG := '[' || l_org_number || '] ' || l_org_name;

        --set session values
        apex_util.set_session_state('P2_EE_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER', out_emp_employee_number);
        apex_util.set_session_state('P2_EE_FULL_NAME', out_emp_full_name);
        apex_util.set_session_state('P2_EE_EMAIL_ADDRESS', out_emp_email_address);
        apex_util.set_session_state('P2_EE_USER_NAME', out_emp_user_name);
        apex_util.set_session_state('P2_EE_JOB', l_job_code || '.' || l_job_title);
        apex_util.set_session_state('P2_EE_POSITION', l_position_number || '.' || l_position_suffix || '.' || l_working_title);
        apex_util.set_session_state('P2_EE_ORG', '[' || l_org_number || '] ' || l_org_name);
        apex_util.set_session_state('P2_EE_SUPV_FULLNAME', out_supv_full_name);
        --apex_util.set_session_state('P2_EE_SUPV_EID', '[' || l_supv_eid || '] ' || l_supv_eid);
        apex_util.set_session_state('P2_EE_SUPV_EMAIL', out_supv_email_address);
        apex_util.set_session_state('P2_EE_SUPV_USERNAME', out_supv_user_name);

END;

I tried calling hri.pkg_apex_eab.get_emp_info from an APEX dynamic action and expected to get several data points back (assigned into other page items).  Instead, I got the error "ORA-06550: line 11, column 19: PLS-00302: component 'GET_EMP_INFO' must be declared".

This is how you're calling it:
hri.pkg_apex_eab.get_emp_info

which means that:

procedure name is get_emp_info
it is part of the pkg_apex_eab package ...
... owned by user named hri

Questions/suggestions:

is Apex workspace allowed to work with the hri user? If not, ask Apex admin to do that
you didn't say which database user is used when developing this application. If it is not hri, did you grant execute privileges from hri to your current user?

Note that this is NOT Apex user, the one you're entering when connecting to Apex (you have to specify workspace name, username and password - that's Apex side of the story). I'm talking about Oracle user.




This was a permission issue on the user as you noted (along with a couple non-critical mistakes in the calling code).  Thank you very much!

You're welcome; I'm glad you made it work.
